# Ethics of answering exam and/or test questions

Tags: discussion, homework

The daily list of questions I see here seems to be distinctly of the homework/other assignment type variety, ranging from a measly school level to graduate level. To me these questions look (almost) uniquely identifiable. While logistically it would be a nightmare to "police" meticulously the cheaters, should not the community take the stance that such questions be not answered? Or would the whole SE collapse without the homework/assignment exercises cohort of users?

Comment: See [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19288/moderators-not-having-a-uniform-response-to-flags-about-potentially-graded-assig).

Comment: @PedroTamaroff but you say don't flag competition questions from your quote, but in fact, MSE shuts down all ongoing competition questions until after the competition has ended. Isn't that quote and MSE actions in direct conflict with each other?

Comment: @Dustin That's not something I said. It is merely a quote I found relevant to the discussion.

Answer (score 2):

All right, I have read @Pedro Tamaroff's leads and I see this is a contentious issue. May I suggest then some middle ground: Surely not being paranoid, surely not sitting there explicitly catching the cheaters, but exercising prudence in answering those almost uniquely identifiable homework questions. Otherwise, this looks overwhelmingly like a school homework site. I am of course aware that one can have a philosophical stance that a small piece of real gold takes a lot of ore to distil...

P.s. Needless to say, cheaters mostly cheat on themselves, but they also create, at least immediate unfair situation to their peers. I have a personal vendetta on this one: Many of my peers who copied my papers and homework in my undergraduate days (should I say they were outright pathetic in their academic performance) hold much better positions than I today. So cheating pays. No?

Comment: Some times cheaters get caught as well, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169278/probability-that-the-median-of-three-numbers-is-in-a-certain-range#comment2389381_1169278). However, MSE still wont stop the question. Now that professor just needs to determine who it was.

Comment: Thaks @dustin. It is fairly easy to determine for those who care to. You look into a fairly positively correlated scatter plot of homework scores and test scores. Then you look for the outliers -- high homework scores vs low test scores. Simple my dear Watson.

Comment: I think the last comment on personal vendetta is just off-topic, and is better removed.

Comment: If you're gonna assess people's worth by professional accomplishments, then maybe cheating pays. But, if you ask me, 'success' as it is portrayed in american movies, does not adequately encompass the concept of success.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff the "vendeta" part is to show that there are real issues involved in the issues discussed. It is not entirely "I am sitting on the clouds and could care less" point of view, but illustrates why people care about this issue. It is often more valuable than the question itself.

Comment: @Rado The comment is off topic because you cannot possibly know these people are more successful than you because they have cheated. It's a shot in the dark that brings only drama to the discussion.

Comment: Sorry @PedroTamaroff but I have a distinct feeling that you brought the drama in, where there was none.